# How to make images with links fade when hovering

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm quite a noob when it comes to CSS and HTML stuff, but I have been able to tweak our Wordpress website quite well so far.... as long as nothing too technical is needed.

I have this code for images to fade on `hover` which I copied from another answered question:

```
img {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}​
```

What I want is for this fade hover effect to work only on images with links. Right now it affects all my images, even those with no links.

I tried doing

```
a.img {
        opacity: 1.0;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
a.img:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
        transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
```

but it did not work at all.
Any simple way to fix this?

Comment: Please add the html so we can see what your images-with-links look like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `a.img` please use a > img
So in your code

```
a > img{
  //... your code
}
a > img:hover{
  //... your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It works.... Only problem now is my homepage slider image, which I inserted with shortcodes, which does not have a link (as I did not put one), there is <a> tag before the <img src> and I don't really know how to remove it. So the <a> tag causes the slider image to have the hover effect which I do not specifically want for it... I tried lifting out the html code from the "inspect" mode for the slider image and replacing the shortcodes, at the same time manually removing all the <a> tags... but the slider image just froze there and doesn't slide.

Comment: that `a` tag in the image slider definitely cannot have to do with the CSS, so that's a separate problem... Look at the HTML structure of the slider in the browser tools and post that HTML code in a new question. There will be a way to have a selector that only applies *outside*  the slider structure.

Comment: @ilkl your question is so general and not specific so I couldn't catch up correct answer. You said you used shortcode, which I am quite not sure. Please explain more what framework do you use and how you implement shortcode in your platform. I am looking for sensible questions because I am happy to answer your question.

Comment: @ilkl your question is so general and not specific so I couldn't catch up correct answer. You said you used shortcode, which I am quite not sure. Please explain more what framework do you use and how you implement shortcode in your platform. I am looking for sensible questions because I am happy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The image is a *child*  of the link, so your CSS selectors need to be `a img {...}` and `a img:hover  {...}` - with a space between the two. Also `a > img {...}` and `a > img:hover  {...}` is possible (which requires it to be a *direct*  child).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It works.... Only problem now is my homepage slider image, which I inserted with shortcodes, which does not have a link (as I did not put one), there is <a> tag before the <img src> and I don't really know how to remove it. So the <a> tag causes the slider image to have the hover effect which I do not specifically want for it... I tried lifting out the html code from the "inspect" mode for the slider image and replacing the shortcodes, at the same time manually removing all the <a> tags... but the slider image just froze there and doesn't slide.